# Java Generics with class object as generic type

Tags: java, generics

I want to create a Java Object for a class that is defined using generics.
Specifically, i want to create a List of Objects of class that is determined at runtime.

I would want something like

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("MyClass");
List<clazz> myList = new ArrayList<>(); // This isn't allowed
```

Defining an array of object would allow me to store a list of MyClass type objects, but that would lead to casting the objects every-time the object is fetched from the list, i would like to avoid such a scenario.

Is there a way to achieve something like the above code using java.

Comment: "but that would lead to casting the objects every-time the object is fetched from the list, i would like to avoid such a scenario."  Nothing you can do will avoid having to cast the objects every time, except doing an unsafe cast on the list, which is not unreasonable.

Comment: @LouisWasserman but how do we cast to the List<clazz> since this structure isn't allowed by java, casting single objects with Reflections is simple, but can we cast a Generic class using the same syntax?

Comment: This is not possible as generic types are resolved at compile time, so at runtime generic types basically don't exist. How do you expect to use the list after its declaration?. Anyway, depending on how you resolve it, casting should not be of concern.

Comment: You don't.  Write `List` without generics.  If you ever have a `Class<T>`, you can cast it to a `List<T>`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I would favor `List<?>` over a raw List.  One less warning.

Comment: @VGR unfortunately this would make the list read only

Comment: @Amal J: I don't really understand this: You say that you would need to "casting the objects every-time the object is fetched from the list". But if the `clazz` type is not known until runtime, how do you know what to cast *to*? Which type do you cast to?

Comment: @Eugene The approach suggested by you wasn't feasible in my case. Thanks for the suggestion anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you *know* that class, you could (with a warning) cast the `List` itself; but you would still need to know the class name and some checks for that, like for example:

```
if(clazz.getName().equals("java.lang.String")) {
     // warning here
     yourList = (List<String>) yourList; 
}
```

Comment: The class name is determined at runtime and it can be a variety of classes, and writing this kind of logic for a solution won't be possible.

Comment: @AmanJ can your classes may be extend a common interface, so that you could cast to `List<ThatInterface>`? Otherwise casting each element will be the only solution

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Generics in Java is just a compile-time type checking mechanism. If you don't know the type until runtime, then, obviously, it cannot be used for compile-time type checking. The compiler can't determine at compile time what types to allow you to put into or get out of a `List<clazz>`, so it's no more meaningful than just a raw type `List`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you want to know if is possible for the compiler to know the runtime type while it is limited to the compile type.

You can't. And your hypothesis is also wrong:

> Defining an array of object would allow me to store a list of MyClass
>   type objects, but that would lead to casting the objects every-time
>   the object is fetched from the list, i would like to avoid such a
>   scenario.

In Java, generics does not remove the cast: it is still there in the form of type erasure and (hidden) cast. When you do `List<String>`, you merely ask the compiler to hide the cast in operation such as `T get(int)`: there will be a cast to `String`.

If you want to use the compile time information, than that would mean you already have/know the type `MyClass` available at compile time and you would not use `Class::forName` but `MyClass.class` which would return a `Class<MyClass>`.

What you can do is either:

1. Use an interface if you have a common ground for theses classes (like JDBC `Driver`).
2. Cast the raw list into a known type, for example using `Class::isAssignableFrom`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a little trick that can be used to work with a specific unknown type: Declare a type parameter that is only used for the unknown type:

```
public <T> void worksWithSomeUnknownClass() throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) Class.forName("MyClass");

    T obj = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();

    List<T> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    myList.add(obj);
}
```

This solution is very limited though. It makes sure that you don't mix it up with other unknown types or `Object`, but you can not really *do* anything with `T`. And you have to declare a type parameter on every method that uses it.